# Change an input value and submit the form on keypress (not just enter to send)

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I'm really confused. I want to make a sort of a hotkey that changes the value of a hidden input field and submits the form. How can I do that? I've read numerous blogs and tutorials but all assume that I just want to submit the filled form after pressing enter. While I just don't understand how the very "structure" of a form acts in javascript.

Should I fill the hidden input like this:

```
document.getElementById('foo').value='bar'
```

I don't think there's even a way to see if its value was changed so I'm not sure.

And then, how do I submit the form, if I have:

```
<form name='myform' method='post' action='url.html'>
```

I tried `document.myform.submit()` and `document.myform.form.submit()`, and I've also tried giving the form an id and using `document.getElementById('myformid').submit()` but none of these work! I usually get the error `TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object`.

I'm new to javascript, I'm used to working with python but it has a completely different philosophy, and maybe that's the source of my confusion. I'd very appreciate some explanation, not just a code snippet.

Thanks!

Comment: Please clarify that you want to change the value of hidden input by pressing hotkey or just want to submit the form.

Comment: Assuming the hidden input has `id="foo"` then yes, the code you've shown is the way to set its value. Giving the form `id="myformid"` and using `document.getElementById('myformid').submit()` should work, otherwise `document.forms.myform.submit()` should work with your existing `name="myform"` attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always check the hidden field with the Development Tools of your Browser - just press F12 and you will see it. Go to the DOM list (within the Development Tool) and then you see the actual value of that field.
To submit a form via JavaScript normally `document.name.submit()` is enough. Another option is that you use e.g. jQuery to submit a form via AJAX (with the help of jQuery.serialize)

Comment: Cool, I didn't know you can check that in Development Tools! And it works now, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `document.getElementById('myformid').submit()` you have to give an ID to your form like that :

```
<form name='myform' id="myform" method='post' action='url.html'>
```

It's the same thing about your hidden field.

`document.getElementById('foo').value='bar'` assume you have an hidden like that :

```
<input type="hidden" name="foo" id="foo" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following approach

```
<form name='myform' method='post' action='url.html'>
   // your fields here

   // then use a input type button to have a button and define an on click event
</form>


<script type = "text/javscript">
use the event in your script
//change your hidden field value here and 
// submit the form by 
myform.submit();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ajax or jquery as there is a function named on key up it means after pressing a key on the last field which ever you choose as you leave the key on keyboard it will submit the forms.

check this okay http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_livesearch.asp